# how to set alarm on monday using alarm manager in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am trying to set alarm on Monday but its not working proper so how to set alarm on Monday only once time.

```
if (chk_wednesday.isChecked()) {
                        weekday = 7 - calNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, weekday);
                        forday(weekday);
                        }


public void forday(int week) {

                days = calNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                month = calNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                year = calNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calSet.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
            // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        Log.i("time1", "" + calSet.getTimeInMillis());
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    }
```

Any one help me.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, where `day_of_week`, `hour`, `minute` define the day and time you want the alarm to occur. You set calSet to the appropriate time for this week. Then, if that time has already passed this week, you add a week so it will be set to the appropriate time for next week.

```
calNow = Calendar.getInstance();

calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day_of_week);
calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if (calSet.before(calNow)) {
    nextAlarm.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
}
```

Comment: which value pass in day_of_week for thursday ?

Comment: Thursday would be 5. You can see all the values [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) by clicking each day of the week.